# Exclude results that contains special characters from elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I already look a lot to find an answer but nothing is working for, so this is my problem, I have an index with a field "name" of type string, I do a simple full text search with match_phrase but that field sometimes is a string compound of few words separated by comma, point, slash or hyphen, for example "engineer,operator,maintenance". I need to exclude those results,for example if I have the next names:

1. "engineer,operator,maintenance"
2. "engineer"
3. "industrial engineer

If I search "engineer", I want to get the last two results and exlude the first. I tried with a must not clause like this:

```
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "must": {
      "match_phrase": {
        "name": "Vendedor"
      }
    },
    "must_not":{
      "match":{
        "name": "\."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried with regular expression too but it always get me the results with the wrong characters:

```
"must_not":{
      "regexp":{
        "name": ".*[\-\.\/\.].*"
      }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong or what should be the way to acomplish this task?

Answer (score 1):

In index settings you can add a char filter and pattern like that, but then you need to reindex, please, look here for more details https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-analyzer.html

```
              "char_filter": {
                  "pattern": {
                     "pattern": "\\W+",
                     "type": "pattern_replace",
                     "replacement": " "
                  },
                  "html": {
                     "type": "html_strip"
                  }
               }
```

Comment: Hi, I don't need to replace the wrong characters, what I need is to exclude the results thats contains those characters. I edit my answer with an example

Comment: Hi, string fields are analyzed by default in ElasticSearch. Have you tried by setting it to not_analyzed in the mapping? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_exact_values.html#_term_filter_with_text